# Bug spray on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, maseches-shabbos, responsa

Can one spray themselves with bug spray on Shabbat or no? I believe it’s brought down by the Mishnah that one can’t Delouse on shabbos, does this count? Is there a responsa on this? Thanks

Comment: Insect repellant spray is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dinonline quotes two sources (Shmiras Shabbos Khilchoso 25-4,6, Orchos Shabbos 14-28) and says that it is not allowed to spray it directly unto the insects, because we cannot kill insects on Shabbos. Spraying it on yourself should be fine, as the article says "It is permitted to spray it a way that will not kill them, but chase them away, such as spraying the room with it".

The article [says](https://dinonline.org/2020/07/07/insect-repellent-on-bugs-on-shabbos/):

> We are not allowed to kill insects on Shabbos, therefore spraying an insecticide on bugs is not permitted on Shabbos. Insect repellants very often contain insecticides in them as their active ingredients, and therefore should not be sprayed on or near the bugs, because it will kill them. It is permitted to spray it a way that will not kill them, but chase them away, such as spraying the room with it, (and keeping an open window) so they will only be repelled and not killed.

See also [DailyHalacha quotes](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/m/halacha.aspx?id=964)